# Convergence of integers by transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, analysis, linear-transformations, arithmetic-combinatorics

Let $x=(a,b)$, where $a,b$ are in $N$

Now we have the transformations:
$$T_1(x) = (ka, b+1)$$ 
$$T_2(x) = (b,a)$$ where $k$ is in $N$.
Where the order of choosing a transformation is not fixed. 
(E.g. you can first apply 3 times $$T_1(x)$$, then $$T_2(x)$$

Will we for all $(a,b)$ produce $a=b$ by only being allowed to use these two transformations? If so, is this true for every $k$? I'm specifically interested in the case $k=2$ though.

Comment: Do you mean that they are integers by $N>0$?

Comment: Are you supposed to alternate $T_1$ and $T_2$? or can you do any sequence you like of the two transformations? It's clear that sometimes you will produce $a=b$, e.g., applying $T_1$ to $(3,5)$ (with $k=2$) produces $(6,6)$. The question needs a lot of detail added before it becomes a real question.

Comment: The order by which you choose the transformations is irrelivant.

Comment: OK, so, are you happy with the answer for $k=2$ that applying $T_1$ to $(3,5)$ produces $(6,6)$? or do you want something more than that? Please, please edit your question so it becomes clear what you actually want. Oh, and if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in the comment.

Comment: You're completely right, Gerry Myerson. I was being unclear. Edited the OP!

Comment: Still not clear. Does "for any $(a,b)$" mean "for some $(a,b)$" or does it mean "for every $(a,b)$"?

Comment: For all $(a,b)$ @gerry

Comment: Looks like a hard question. E.g., $(2,4)\to(4,2)\to(8,3)\to(16,4)\to(4,16)\to(8,17)\to(17,8)\to(34,9)\to(9,34)\to(18,35)\to(36,36)$.

Comment: @gerry nice find! if we can prove that all $$(a,b)=(1,1)(mod 2)$$ can go to (x,x) we are also done since all pairs with one or two even integers can transform to this form

Comment: Bumping this up again!